# how do we get the output of a subprocess of a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Could someone share a sample of python script that shows the output of a subprocess (java kicked off by file.bin) of a subprocess (kicking off a file.bin) ?

The subprocess (java kicked off by file.bin) of a subprocess (kicking off a file.bin) looks like this below from a `ps -ef | grep java`

`rrr   26267 26266  0 16:05 pts/12   00:00:03 /tmp/install.dir.26267/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java com.rew.erg.REW /tmp/install.dir.26267/temp.erg /tmp/env.properties.26267 "-i" "console"`

How do we hook up to the subprocess of another subprocess and perform interaction with it like an expect or pexpect script?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, here is just an example:

```
import subprocess
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
    ret = ex.returncode
```

Comment: Hi Wu Li thanks for responding; we are new to python; we got this error     "except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CalledProcessError'"